# Operators allowed in SliceQuery

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra, predicate, hector

I am writing a java code to access data stored in Cassandra. I am using Hector API.

To retrieve the data, i am using slice query. But it seems it supports only five arithmetic operators and that too with AND operator.

Is there any way to write predicate with OR operator or to query based on contains functionality as in string. ???

Comment: Are you asking whether it's possible to do the equivalent of SQL "like" queries?